# From the curl command console output grep for some pattern files and copy them to a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have requirement where I need to "grep for some pattern files and copy them to a directory from the curl command console output".

I need all this in a shell script.

Ex:

```
1)$ curl -sk -u username:password https://localhost:port/appname/config/ >/tmp/appname.txt
2)$ `egrep '\.truststore$|\.keystore$|\.jks$|\.pem$' /tmp/appname.txt | grep -v pass | sort`
```

output:

```
root4.file=/abc/xyz/app/etc/pvt/old.pem
root3.file=/app/etc/pvt/bbc.pem
root1.File=/app/etc/pvt/abc.pem
db.cluster.trustore=/app/etc/pvt/dbdir/qa-db.jks
someprocess.keystore.path=/app/etc/pvt/qa-key.jks
someprocess.keystore.filename=/homelocation/app/appdir/conf/qa.jks
someprocess..trsustore.filename=/homelocation/app/appdir/conf/qa.jks
newprocess.trustore.filename=/app/etc/dir2/app.jks
otherproces.keystore.filename=/app/etc/new/some.jks
some.tokenfile=/homelocation/apps/etc/somedir/test2.pem.pem
newprocess.filename=qa-key2.jks
appname.keystore.filename=qa.key1.jks
appservice.filename=qa.key3.jks
appname2.filename=qa.new.key4.jks
some3.filename=qa-test_key.jks
some.filename=qa-test_key.jks
```

3)Now I need the above files with only full path needs to be copied to some directory "/tmp/newdir"

eg- only below files needs to be copied which are present on the machine.

```
root4.file=/abc/xyz/app/etc/pvt/old.pem
root3.file=/app/etc/pvt/bbc.pem
root1.File=/app/etc/pvt/abc.pem
db.cluster.trustore=/app/etc/pvt/dbdir/qa-db.jks
someprocess.keystore.path=/app/etc/pvt/qa-key.jks
someprocess.keystore.filename=/homelocation/app/appdir/conf/qa.jks
someprocess..trsustore.filename=/homelocation/app/appdir/conf/qa.jks
newprocess.trustore.filename=/app/etc/dir2/app.jks
otherproces.keystore.filename=/app/etc/new/some.jks
some.tokenfile=/homelocation/apps/etc/somedir/test2.pem.pem
```

These needs to be ignored which doesn't have absolute path.

```
newprocess.filename = qa-key2.jks
appname.keystore.filename= qa.key1.jks
appservice.filename = qa.key3.jks
appname2.filename= qa.new.key4.jks
some3.filename =qa-test_key.jks
some.filename= qa-test_key.jks
```

Please help me on the above request. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the directory structure:

```
cut -d'=' -f2 `command2 output` | grep '^/' | xargs -i cp --parents {} /tmp/newdir/
```

Just remove the `--parents` flag in `cp` if you only need to copy over the files.

**Edit**

Just to be clear, the `command2 output` is just there as a placeholder for the output of your second command since you seem to be writing your output to a file. Of course, a pipe would still work e.g.

```
command2 | cut -d'=' -f2 | grep '^/' | xargs -i cp --parents {} /tmp/newdir/
```

Comment: I have tried this I worked egrep '\.truststore$|\.keystore$|\.jks$|\.pem$' /tmp/$app.txt | grep -v pass | sort | cut -d '=' -f2 | grep "^\/" | xargs -i {} cp {} $logDir